# Find Value A inside of Matrix NxN an return corresponding value

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, excel-2010

i currently dealing with an issue:

[image]

I want to look for the Value "A" inside of a matrix NxN and return the corresponding real_value.
So my problem is that, with Vlookup, it is searching only inside the first column, but as you may see in my example, I do have values which appear also in other columns. Therefore i would like to receive the real_value 1 and 3 ( for the example in the attached pic). Also tried it with Index and match but still didn't found a good solution.

I hope one can help me out.

Comment: Where would you like your results to show? Also, what have you tried yourself? Can you include that attempt into your question.

Comment: Well in the beginning i've tried Vlookup(A2,C2:G4,5,FALSE), up to that point, i didn't really knew that VLookup looks only for the very first column. Afterwards I have tried Index(G:G,Match(A2,C2:E4,0)), but as well didn't do what i want.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on below `Array` formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,$E$2:$G$4)),ROW($E$2:$G$4),""),ROW(1:1))-ROW($E$1)),"")
```

[image]

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as array formula.

Comment: it worked with some minor changes:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2,$C$2:$E$4)),ROW($E$2:$E$4),""),ROW(1:1))-ROW($E$1)),"")`

Thank you for the help! Now i need to figure out, how to return the second real_value ( i.e. for the searched value a it shall be (1, 3) ( because it appears in V1 and V2 )

Comment: After putting formula just drag and down.